How to inspect the dom of the HTML date picker calendar?
I am using the native HTML date picker which I show with HTML showPicker() method. I need to write a e2e test (using Playwright) where I can open the calendar and click on the different date numbers.
The issue I am having is that I cannot keep the calendar open to inspect the dom. It disappears as soon as I click anywhere.
I tried placing a breakpoint on the input element with subtree modification but it did not help. I also tried playwright's codegen. I was able to click on the date number elements but Playwrights codgen debugger did not output any locators for it.
Any idea on how I can inspect the DOM of the HTML date picker?
EDIT: Code that I am using
      <label for="date">
        <input
          required
          @change="${this._setDateFromPicker}"
          hidden
          class="date-input"
          type="date"
          value="${this.value}">
        </input>

        <md-outlined-button
          @click=${this._openPicker}
          class="date-btn">
          ${this.displayDate}
        </md-outlined-button>
      </label>




Sidenote: your label is invalid. The for attribute is for pointing to the id attribute of the input element it's a label for, but your input has no id attribute.

You don't actually care about how the user inputs a value, so you don't care about "clicking the date picker" and you definitely don't care about navigating the built-in date picker. You already know that works: that was the browser's responsibility (browser manufacturers already have tests for that in place, our tests are not to double-check their work).
Instead, what you want to know is that that your code does the right thing with the user's input, so trigger the user input using a playwright action:
...

await page.getByLabel('some-date').fill('2020-02-02');

...


I did not try this because I did not think the fill would work. That would be great if it does. I did not think it would work because you cannot type in the input field

You can: it would be incredibly bad for accessibility if you couldn't, especially because it's a form input, so it's just a field that captures a string. The various type indicators give you different ways to input that string, but you can always type while focused on an input field.

(with the only exceptions of course being the type="file" input, since that's not user input but system data, and the various button types, for which you should use <button> instead)

I am trying this but the datepicker value is not getting set with await page.locator('#add-transaction input[type="date"]').fill('1999-09-13');

Playwright doesn't error or complain... the input value just doesn't contain the fill() value

It most certainly will, so now you have a new thing to debug: you can trivially confirm that the value is there by eval'ing a change listener on the input element that runs a console.log(event.target.value), with the standard playwright console passthrough before you trigger your fill. And if after debugging for a bit you can't figure out what is going on, it really is time for a [mcve] in your post. And that's more work for you, but it's work you were already expected to have done before.

Yep, I have a console.log() for the change event on the input but it does not fire with the fill(). I also paused the test after the fill, manually saved the form, and verified the new fill date was not set.

I don't think it would matter since the selector is finding the element ok, but I am using lit library that uses shadow dom.

then put that in your post. Why are you giving new details in a comment instead of having that in information in your post from the start? Go (re)read the posting guidelines, and then edit your post accordingly. Because if you're using more than just HTML and playwright, talk about that in your post, tag it properly, and show a [mcve] so others can confirm the problem. Stackoverflow is not chat-based, or comments-based: your post should contain all the details someone needs to answer the question it asks, including which frameworks you're using, which versions, etc.
